# Custom 404 with nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I've reviewed the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/views) and various blog posts. I've created an `errors.vue` file under layouts.

Yet my custom 404 error message is not displayed.

I've also looked at [these docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate#fallback) and defined the fallback in the config, again, no custom 404.

Where am I going wrong? It's a static site with translations.

Comment: Can you please share the full template file you've created?

Comment: Please note that you should name your page "error.vue" and not "errors.vue" (in plural). I have used this feature successfully with the same instructions you followed.

Comment: @gijoe fails whichever file name I use.